# Краш программы при завершении работы слота (Qt/C++)

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть однопоточный сервер, который работает с клиентами.
Также есть функция, которая принимает подключение и сохраняет его в массив.

```
void Server::ConnectClient()
{
    // берем следующее подключение
    QTcpSocket *_socket = nextPendingConnection();

    // выводим сообщение о новом подключении и увеличиваем счетчик юзеров
    CountConnection++;
    qDebug() << "New connection\n" << "Active connection: " << CountConnection << '\n';

    // ищем свободное место в массиве
    int IndFreePlace = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTION; i++)
        if (!mUsers[i]) {
            IndFreePlace = i;
            break;
        }

    // добавляем юзера в список, делаем connect'ы
    mUsers[IndFreePlace] = new User(_socket, IndFreePlace);
    connect(mUsers[IndFreePlace], &User::SignalMyReadyRead, this, &Server::CommandHandler);
    connect(mUsers[IndFreePlace], &User::SignalMyDisconnect, this, &Server::DisconnectClient);
}
```

Сам клиент, как видно, хранит в себе все необходимые данные и сокет. Также он может испускать 2 сигнала: приход данных и отключение клиента. Все работает отлично, но когда клиент отключается и срабатывает слот Server::DisconnectClient, этот самый слот завершается с ошибкой:

```
void Server::DisconnectClient(int _id)
{
    // удаляем юзера из канала
    if (mUsers[_id]->GetCurrentChannel())
        mUsers[_id]->GetCurrentChannel()->DeleteUser(mUsers[_id]->GetUserName());

    // обнуляем элемент списка
    qDebug() << "Client " << mUsers[_id]->GetUserName() << " disconnected";
    delete mUsers[_id];
    mUsers[_id] = nullptr;

    CountConnection--;
    qDebug() << "Active connection: " << CountConnection;
}
```

После выполнения этого слота сервер перестает работать, и остается только закрыть программу.
Отладчик выдает следующее: при выходе из слота отключения я попадаю в файл moc_user.cpp.
В этом файле очень много ошибок, будто забыт какой-то include. Сама отладка останавливается в функции

```
// SIGNAL 0
void User::SignalMyDisconnect(int _t1)
{
    void *_a[] = { nullptr, const_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&_t1)) };
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, _a);
}
```

на последней строке. У меня, кроме идеи, что ошибка возникает из-за удаления юзера, который посылает сигнал, больше ничего нет... Хотя я пробовал не удалять его, но тогда происходит утечка памяти, а ошибка остается.
В общем, я уже совсем не знаю, в чем дело. Я новичок, и взялся за задачу, которая оказалась не по моему уму пока что. Но доделать-то надо...
Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ прост - нельзя удалять объект в его слоте. Это 100% приводит к падениям. Специально для этого придумали [deleteLater()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater). Удаление объекта будет помещено в очередь событий и будет удалено после выполнения слота.

Правда, возможно Вам нужно будет переделать немного логику списка подключений - просто добавлять-удалять. Но для начала просто попробуйте вместо

```
delete mUsers[_id];
```

вызвать

```
mUsers[_id]->deleteLater();
```

Comment: большое спасибо!!! Вы так меня выручили)
Не знал про функцию deleteLater()